# Custom membership with SQL Database?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership, custom-membershipprovider

I want to implement custom membership using SQL database.I searched alot but couldn't find any good tutorial .can anybody help to take a good start ?
I am using asp.net with c#.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Start with code below:

```
using System;    
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

public class MyMembershipProvider: SqlMembershipProvider
{
}
```